# php form problems (not displaying php echo)

Tags: php, html

I've been making a website that requires a login, and I made it so that if the form is submitted, a little text will appear under the H1 tag in PHP that says Form Submitted. Right now that text isn't popping up. What did I do wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
        $result = "Form Submitted";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <h1>My email form</h1>
                    <?php echo $result; ?>

                    <form method = "post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for = "name">Your Name: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name = "name" />
                        </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for = "email">Your Email: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="email" name = "email" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for = "comment">Your Comment: </label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name = "comment" /></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" id = "button" name = "submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter"/>


                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I can see on http://www.remweb.org, PHP doesn't running on your server. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkwCW.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Change your button to a submit button**..

That is, replace

```
<input type="button" id = "button" name = "submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter"/>
```

with

```
<input type="submit" id = "button" name = "submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter"/>
```

Comment: The form is submitting, but itt still is not showing the php echo under the H1.

Comment: How does it submit without a submit button?

Comment: I made the change you said, but the php is still not showing up. By submitting, I mean the page reloads.

Comment: please add `var_dump($_POST);` before that if statement and please tell me what you are getting.

Comment: Is this what you mean:                                                                                   <?php
        var_dump($_POST);
 if ($_POST["submit"]) {
  $result = "Form Submitted!";
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                         I still don't see the php text. If you want, this code is live at www.remweb.org, so you can see yourself.

Comment: add `action=""` to your `<form>`

Comment: or `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>"`

Comment: Still not seeing the php echo

Comment: try replacing your `<form>` with `<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post">`

Comment: sorry..missing `"` ..replace it as `<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">`

Comment: now it's taking me to a page that says 404 not found/url not found

Comment: fix the error in the form tag..you have an `"` before the echo inside the action..

Comment: I don't think I do. I looked and didn't find one. This is what I have:                     <form  method="post" action= <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> >

Comment: Add a `"` after `action=`.. That is enclose that php code inside "

Comment: Same problem. This is what I have: <form  method="post" action=" <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" >

Comment: Still u have some error with the form tag as there is a `">` in your page

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $result = "Form Submitted";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" id ="button" name ="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enter"/>

<?php
    $result = "";
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $result .= "Form Submitted";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: URL pulled from comments in another answer.

> *"If you want, this code is live at www.remweb.org, so you can see yourself. –  Aaron Janke 2 hours ago"*

There are a few things wrong here.

Firstly, your domain http://www.remweb.org/ has an index file named `index.html` (I typed in the index.html at the end just to make sure it was the same file/form), and in doing http://www.remweb.org/index.html it showed the form. Your server seems to be using the `.html` file as its default index.

- I also (guessed and) went to http://www.remweb.org/index.php to see if you did have an PHP index file, and it showed "hello", therefore this tells me that PHP seems to be running.

Therefore, you need to replace the `.html` version with `.php` or rename your posted code's file as "form.php" for example, and it will work.

NOTA: http://www.remweb.org/index.html (being your form) contains PHP directives that are not being parsed by your server and does not by default.

Either you do as I suggest, or instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP.

Plus, since your form contains 3 elements and the action is used for the same page, you need to use `!empty()` for those in order to echo the results of those input.

I.e.

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    echo $name;

}
```

and do the same for the others.

Or, seperate your `.html` file from PHP and use a file pointer for the action and echo everything in the other file.

I.e.: `action="action_file.php"`

and hold the PHP directives in that file.

- Your submit button's type `<input type="button"` needs to be a "submit" type and not "button" `<input type="submit"`